# Toast Notification Format to Both WIndows Store App and Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows, azure, windows-phone-8, notifications, toast

people have said they can push same toast notification from Azure notification hub to both windows 8 apps and windows phone 8 apps. My question is what the toast looks like for that..

From the examples, for windows 8, the format is like this

```
<toast>
    <visual>
        <binding template="ToastText01">
            <text id="1">bodyText</text>
        </binding>  
    </visual>
</toast>
```

For windows phone, it's

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wp:Notification xmlns:wp="WPNotification">
    <wp:Toast>
        <wp:Text1>[string]</wp:Text1>
    </wp:Toast>
</wp:Notification>
```

So how do we make the toast compatible to both?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. You need to send the appropriate format content to the appropriate devices.